# Straight Teeth Generator in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I need to put the functionality to my Wordpress site. Please check the functionality below link:
https://www.invisalign.co.uk/smile-view#search.
Upload image with teeth and convert into straight teeth. Please help me how can I do it as I did not use iframe as in iframe we did not be able to hide header footer etc. Please help
I am trying to add teeth technology.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the code you have already tried for this feature.